# Git pulls files in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, git-pull

I use Git pull to download changes from remote repo to my local dev folder.
the problem is every time I pull changes, git downloads some file that exists in .gitignore file (e.g. /app/config/config.yml)

what am I doing wrong ??
here is my .gitignore

```
# Parameters
/app/config/parameters.yml
/app/config/parameters.ini
/app/config/config.yml
```

but when I pull `git pull` I find a new config.yml !!

Comment: Is this your local gitignore, or is it also in the remote?

Comment: What was wrong with the results you got from googling "Git pulls files in .gitignore"?

Comment: @jthill Funny because now my googling "Git pulls files in .gitignore now" returns this question as the first result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.gitignore` only ignores untracked files. It does not have any influence to the ones that have already been committed.

> The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked.

References:

- http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 12):

Check if your local config.yml is actualy ignored, or if it is currently versioned.

```
git check-ignore -v -- app/config/config.yml
```

If it isn't ignored, you need to remove from the index and record that deletion

```
git rm --cached -- app/config/config.yml
git commit -m "delete config.yml"
git push
```

Then the next pull wouldn't bring that file back.

But, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843187/git-pulls-files-in-gitignore/26843265?noredirect=1#comment88318435_26843265) by [Shichu Zhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5426033/shichu-zhu), it also means the next `git pull` will, for *other* collaborator, will delete their local `config.yml`.
So you need to communicate that, for them to do [something like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35317422/6309).

Comment: If you remove & push, then collaborators' local config.yml will be deleted when they do a git pull. Need to be cautious this is expected outcome.

Comment: @ShichuZhu Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.